# iterate in perl with a specific interval

Tags: perl

Sorry for my noobness,
This iterates the entire table. However, I want to iterate starting from the 2nd row. How to do that.

```
foreach my $row ($table->rows) {
    print join(',', @$row), "\n";
}
```

thanks.

Comment: You should perhaps mention what kind of object `$table` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @rows = $table->rows;
for my $row (@rows[ 1 .. $#rows ]) {
    print join(',', @$row), "\n";
}
```